# JSON format getting only one column

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PHP so far I managed to get the following output from database in JSON format.I created an array result which returns workorderName, but I want to get workOrderId also in the same array so that I can use it in android string request.

```
   {
    "result": [
        {
            "$workOrderName": "electrician"
        },
        {
            "$workOrderName": "plumber"
        },
        {
            "$workOrderName": "carpenter"
        }
    ]
}
```

my php code is

```
<?PHP
require_once('connection.php');
$workName = "SELECT work_order_id,workorder_name FROM workorder_category";
$con=mysqli_connect($server_name,$user_name,$password,$db);
$r = mysqli_query($con,$workName);
$result = array();
$resultArr = array('success' => true);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
        array_push($result,array('$workOrderName'=>$row['workorder_name']));
        }
echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I want the Output like

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "$workOrderId":"1"
            "$workOrderName": "electrician"
        },
        {
            "$workOrderId":"2"
            "$workOrderName": "plumber"
        },
        {
            "$workOrderId":"3"
            "$workOrderName": "carpenter"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Share the MySQL table with example data also as a ascii data table or provide a sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you didn't mean to have the `$` in the key, but this is easier and will give you the column names (work_order_id, workorder_name) from the table as keys. Make sure to use `mysqli_fetch_assoc`:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){
    $result[] = $row;
}
```

If you want to change the keys then you can alias them in the query and use the above:

```
$workName = "SELECT work_order_id AS workOrderID, workorder_name AS workOrderName FROM workorder_category";
```

Or you could build the array:

```
$result[] = array('workOrderID'   => $row['work_order_id'],
                  'workOrderName' => $row['workorder_name']);
```

Comment: Undefined variable: row in
<b>C:\xampp\htdocs\ttpms\spinnerData.php</b> on line
<b>9</b>
<br />
{"result":{"$workOrderId":null,"$workOrderName":null,"0":{"workorder_name":"electrician"},"1":{"workorder_name":"plumber"},"2":{"workorder_name":"carpenter"}}}

Answer (score -1):

You need to tweak your code to add `$workOrderId` also in the array like below

```
array_push($result,array(
'$workOrderId' => $row['work_order_id']
'$workOrderName' => $row['workorder_name']
));
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help. A proper explanation [would greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made